# Sumir com uma lista ativa quando clicar com em outra

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei 3 listas em html, e fiz um toggleClass para que as listas apareçam e desapareçam, porém quando clico em uma e ela abre, gostaria que todas as outras listas que estão abertas se fechassem... alguém pode me ajudar?

Código:

```js
$('.control-monteseupc').click(function () {
 $(this).toggleClass('active')
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
.control-monteseupc.active .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  <div class="control-monteseupc">
    <h4>item1</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="select"><span class="text-white">item1</span></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="processadores">
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="control-monteseupc">
    <h4>item2</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="select"><span class="text-white">item1</span></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="data">
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="control-monteseupc">
    <h4>item3</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="select"><span class="text-white">item1</span></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="data1">
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e reduzir o problema a um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 1):

Basta remover a classe `.active` de todos os `.control-monteseupc`, exceto do que foi clicado. Para isso você usa o `.not(this)`:

```js
$('.control-monteseupc').click(function () {
  $('.control-monteseupc')
  .not(this) // exclui o elemento clicado
  .removeClass('active');
  
  $(this)
  .toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
.control-monteseupc.active .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> 
  <div class="control-monteseupc">
    <h4>item1</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="select"><span class="text-white">item1</span></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="processadores">
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="control-monteseupc">
    <h4>item2</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="select"><span class="text-white">item2</span></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="data">
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="control-monteseupc">
    <h4>item3</h4>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="select"><span class="text-white">item3</span></div>
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="data1">
        <li>option1</li>
        <li>option2</li>
        <li>option3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Essa isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado!